# How to join to different access database table's in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have two different database. both have a country table in common. Lets consider first table A and second table B. both have a country with a various different field's.in both databse table Common is Country ID.

Now in C# i want to join this two tables. Both are Different Access Database. (A first Accesss database and B second access database)

How do i achieve this ? I got information from some resoruce that you can achieve this by using Linq to Dataset. but as my knowledge linq is mostly for SQL and why only for small purpose go for LINQ as already project is already done only reports part remianing. Please frd's if you have any infromation regarding this share with me.

Waiting for your reply.

Thank you.

Comment: why cant you write a plain sql statement to join these tables.Use [databasename].[TableName] rather than just specifying the table name. and call this sql from C#

Comment: @AshleyJohn that'd be neat trick in ms-access

Comment: @AshleyJohn writing plain sql statement is possible in sql server. i also done in past then i call that query in C#. but here two different access database. How i join this two in efficience way ?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a linked data-source in Access. Then you can run queries against the one database as if it contained both tables.

Comment: Can you give me example in C# with Two diff. Access database ?

Comment: What is suggested above is that you do not use two different databases. A linked table acts as if it is the same as an ordinary table.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite possible to write an sql statement that can be run againt the first database connection that references the second database. There are umpteen examples of connecting to Access in c# on SO.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a 
INNER JOIN [c:\docs\dbfrom.mdb].table1 b 
ON a.id=b.id
```